# Scala via Spark with yarn - curly brackets string missing

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, curly-braces

I made some scala code and it looks like this.

```
object myScalaApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
        val strJson = args.apply(0)
        println( "strJson : " + strJson)
```

and call this scala jar file from yarn.

```
Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
.setAppResource("/usr/local/myJar/myApp.jar")
.setMainClass("com.myScalaApp")
.setMaster("yarn")
.setDeployMode( "cluster")
.addAppArgs( data)
.launch();
```

When I set json string like below

> {\"aaa\" : \"a1111\",\"bbbb\" : \"b1111\"}

it print below (as I expect)

> strJson : {"aaa" : "a1111","bbbb" : "b1111"}

BUT when I set json string like below

> {\"aaa\" : \"a1111\",\"bbbb\" : \"b1111\",\"ccc\" : {\"c1\" :
>   \"c111\"}}

it print below

> strJson : {"aaa" : "a1111","bbbb" : "b1111","ccc" : {"c1" : "c111"

Why do all close curly bracket disappear?

---

extra sample

1

> \"{\"aaa\" : \"a1111\",\"bbbb\" : \"b1111\",\"ccc\" : {\"c1\" :
>   \"c111\"}}\"
>
> strJson : "{"aaa" : "a1111","bbbb" : "b1111","ccc" : {"c1" : "c111""

2

> {\"aaa\" : \"a1111\",\"bbbb\" : \"b1111\",\"ccc\" : {\"c1\" :
>   \"c111\"}a}
>   strJson : {"aaa" : "a1111","bbbb" : "b1111","ccc" : {"c1" : "c111"}a}

Comment: I think your shell is playing tricks on you.

Comment: It might not because I got error when json string is parsing, and It printed on hadoop log.

Comment: Have you tried to put `"` around your string ? like `"{\"aaa\" : \"a1111\",\"bbbb\" : \"b1111\",\"ccc\" : {\"c1\" : \"c111\"}}"`

Comment: @L.CWI Still same. I made some extra sample.

Comment: @J.Done, could you plz let me know if adding a space between }} resolves your issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem happens because of the way YARN tries to replace parameter expansion markers `{{` and `}}` in your command with references to environment variables.

If you for example pass `run_job.sh {{MY_VARIABLE}}` to YARN it will convert it to `run_job.sh $MY_VARIABLE` so that environment variable would be used.

So this issue will happen if you have JSON (or other things with two curly braces next to each other) with nested objects in your command line. This only happens when you use YARN as master and cluster deploy mode. Spark standalone and YARN client mode are not affected.

To fix this issue either use other data format than JSON or make sure that you don't have two curly braces next to each other.

For example with Python you could quickly fix this issue like this:

```py
def fix_json_for_yarn(json_string):
    # See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17814
    # Due to that YARN bug we need to make sure that our json string
    # doesn't contain {{ or }} because those get replaced by YARN.
    return json_string.replace("}}", "} }").replace("{{", "{ {")
```

You can see the problematic YARN code here:

```java
  @VisibleForTesting
  public static String expandEnvironment(String var,
      Path containerLogDir) {
    var = var.replace(ApplicationConstants.LOG_DIR_EXPANSION_VAR,
      containerLogDir.toString());
    var =  var.replace(ApplicationConstants.CLASS_PATH_SEPARATOR,
      File.pathSeparator);

    // replace parameter expansion marker. e.g. {{VAR}} on Windows is replaced
    // as %VAR% and on Linux replaced as "$VAR"
    if (Shell.WINDOWS) {
      var = var.replaceAll("(\\{\\{)|(\\}\\})", "%");
    } else {
      var = var.replace(ApplicationConstants.PARAMETER_EXPANSION_LEFT, "$");
      var = var.replace(ApplicationConstants.PARAMETER_EXPANSION_RIGHT, "");
    }
    return var;
  }
```

See ticket of the problem here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17814

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the double quotes in start and end of the string.
Please try with double quotes as

```
"{\"aaa\" : \"a1111\",\"bbbb\" : \"b1111\",\"ccc\" : {\"c1\" : \"c111\"} }";
```

Comment: still same. }} is repalced as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use triple quotes?

""" {"aaa" : "a1111","bbbb" : "b1111","ccc" : {"c1" : "c111"}} """

Its all lot easier to read, and will solve your problem.

Comment: still same. }} is repalced as empty.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't sure why this is happening, but can solved with added 'space' between curly brackets like below.

> }} -> } }