# how to pass double braces from shell script to python script in spark?

Tags: python, shell, apache-spark, sh, spark-streaming

I have a python script `a.py` which is run on spark. It is submitted by shell script `b.sh`. I need to pass a parameter which contains double braces from `b.sh` to `a.py`. The following is what I did.

In b.sh I wrote:

```
spark_submit=/usr/custom/spark/bin/spark-submit
$spark_submit \
--name "test" \
a.py --param "{'a':{'b':2}}"
```

In a.py I wrote:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--param", type=str) 
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

I wish to get `Namespace(param="{'a':{'b':2}}")`, however it returns `Namespace(param="{'a':{'b':2")`, and the double braces vanished. How can I solve this?

Comment: It works fine on my computer, nothing disappears. Perhaps you should attach a screenshot of the command line.

Comment: I tried on my computer, it works well. However if I run in spark then the braces disappers.

Comment: Try `import sys;print(sys.argv)` to see exactly what Spark is passing to Python. I suspect Spark is processing the arguments in a way that removes }}

Comment: Put a space between them. That said, this isn't something Python itself does; neither does the shell itself.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040793/scala-curly-brackets-string-missing

Comment: @HugoRivera, that's about yarn. Is the OP here using it?

Comment: @HugoRivera Thanks! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by yarn, a tool used by spark with certain configurations. See the answers here: [Scala - curly brackets string missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040793/scala-curly-brackets-string-missing)

Comment: Don't add an answer describing a question as a duplicate -- instead, close it as a duplicate using the "close" button. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of "How to Answer" in the Help Center.